# "OR" rules in .procmailrc with body search

Tags: procmail

According to http://lipas.uwasa.fi/~ts/info/proctips.html#orrules , you can make basic "or" rules in .procmailrc with something like:

```
:0:
* ^From:.*reriksso@([-a-z0-9_]+\.)*helsinki\.fi|\
  ^From:.*era@iki\.fi
${DEFAULT}
```

Normally, you can make a condition checks the body with a condition like

```
* B ?? search_body_for_this
```

However, this overrides the default header/body search area, so I can't do something like

```
* B ?? search_body_for_this|\
  ^From:.*example@example\.com
```

Is there any way I can do "or" rules as conditions that have sub-conditions that search the body and headers separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I misinterpreted your question the first time...

But if I understand you correctly than the solution would be to create two successive rules and using flag E (else if)

```
:0 H
* <header condition>
<action>

:0 EB
* <body condition>
<action>
```

(Header flag set for documentation to explicitly state the purpose of the rule.)

Nontheless, my previous answer might contain something new to you so I just leave it be:

I don't know about your solution, but you can make OR-Rules by using weights

```
:0
* 1^1 some expression
* 1^1 some other expression
/some/destination
```